# Showing that $E[\|X_k\|^2]$ approaches $O(k)$ from below for random $k\times d$ matrix $X$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-matrices

Suppose $X_k$ is a matrix made by stacking $k$ random vectors of unit norm sampled from some sufficiently nice $d$-dimensional distribution.

How would I show that the following quantity is monotonically increasing in $k$ for operator norm $\|\cdot\|$?

$$E[(\|X_k\|-1)^2]/k$$

Expecting it to be true because when $k$ is small relative to $d$, a random vector has high probability to be orthogonal to existing ones and may not affect the norm much.

Simple [simulation](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/mathse-random-matrix-norm.nb)

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you state precisely how the matrix $X_k$ is generated, I do not understand what "stacking" means.

Comment: In statistics it's known as the "data matrix". Each row of $X$ is an IID sample from distribution in $d$ dimensions, so the matrix has shape $k\times d$